# Errors while trying to implement Comparable

Tags: java

I keep getting this error in my user class:

```
User is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(User) in Comparable
```

I'm not sure what it means or what to do to make it work. I did look on other similar posts but don't really understand the responses since they are most of the time specific to someone elses code. I can provide more information about what I'm trying to do if required.

```
public class User implements Comparable < User > {

    private String firstName;
    private String surname;
    private int booksOut;

    User(String inFirstName, String inSurname, int inBooksOut){
        this.firstName = inFirstName;
        this.surname = inSurname;
        this.booksOut = inBooksOut;
    }

    //...

}
```

What i am essentially doing I am creating SortedLinkedList class from LinkedList and I have add method in there which uses compareTo, to order the data in ascending order as they are added.
So when I call

```
 User user1= new User("Dan", "Hill", 0); 
SortedLinkedList LibraryUser = new SortedLinkedList(); 
LibraryUser.add(user1);
```

It creates new object which is saved in the sorted linked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you implement Comparable, java looks for the implementation of compareTo

For example:

(Please note that I made the variables public for simplicity)

```
public class User implements Comparable < User > {

    public String firstName;
    public String surname;
    public int booksOut;

    User(String inFirstName, String inSurname, int inBooksOut){
        this.firstName = inFirstName;
        this.surname = inSurname;
        this.booksOut = inBooksOut;
    }

    public int compareTo(User cmp) {
        int fnCmp = firstName.compareTo(cmp.firstName);
        if (fnCmp != 0) return(fnCmp);
        int snCmp = surname.compareTo(cmp.surname);
        if (snCmp != 0) return(snCmp);
        return(cmp.booksOut-booksOut);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You made your class implement an interface but have not actually implemented its methods.

You either need to make User an abstract class (so that concrete subclasses of it will then need to implement the interface method) or implement the method in the User class.

Answer (score 3):

When your class implements an interface it has to implement the methods declared in that interface, which you are not doing.
you have to implement compareTo(T o) method of Comparable interface.
look at the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) for Comparable .

```
public class User implements Comparable < User > {

   public int compareTo(T o){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class is declared to implement `Comparable` interface, but it does not provide implementation for methods in this interface.

You need to provide implementation for `compareTo(User anotherUser)` method. For example:

```
public int compareTo(User anotherUser) {
    String thisFullName = firstName + lastName;
    String anotherFullName = anotherUser.getFirstName() + anotherUser.getLastName();
    return thisFullName.compareTo(anotherFullName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the javadoc on Comparable.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comparable has one method signature:

```
public int compareTo(T object);
```

Add this code to your user class to make it work:

```
public int compareTo(User u) {
// code to compare this user with u
// i'd recommend comparing the last names, then the first names
}
```